# Jquery search for a class then add one after it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a library that generates an element with a specific class.
I do not want to edit the library at all, how would I create a function with jquery to search for a specific class name and append another class after it?

ie:
Lib creates:

```
<div class="class-lib">
```

Function searches for "class-lib" and adds class-func

```
<div class="class-lib class-func">
```

Comment: Check http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: once the lib has done its job `$('class-lib').addClass('class-func');`

Comment: fascinating what a google search of `jquery add class` turns up....amazing how the first result matches all the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
$( ".class-lib" ).addClass( "class-func" );
```

first part `$( ".class-lib" )` gets reference to the element with class name `class-lib`. Then the second part `.addClass( "class-func" );` adds the class `class-func` to it.

Comment: Thanks! Since a library was generating it I had to use
$(window).load(function(){
  $( ".class-lib" ).addClass( "class-func" );
});

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
$(".class-lib").each(function(){
  $(this).addClass("class-func")
});
```

OR

```
$( "div.class-lib" ).addClass( "class-func" );
```

Comment: `each` is redundant, jQuery loops all elements in collection internally

Comment: The each is unnecessary

Comment: @charlietfl..plz provide me link where its written that each is redundant and dont use each with class names???

Comment: @Kartikeya: when you are applying the same functionality to all div  with that class, then why would you use each function.

Comment: @AmitKumar..yes that is true.. i agree..but you cannot say its redundant... that is why i posted two answers here..

Comment: @Kartikeya: i think , before edit you have only one answer with each loop.

Comment: @AmitKumar...yes you are absolutely correct ... i first posted one answer and after that i posted another way also ... within 5 min of answering we can make constructive modifications in our answer.

Comment: @Kartikeya Your first answer _is_ redundant. I'm not sure why you insist on keeping your old answers around after you've come up with better ones. You should delete the old answers and keep the good ones. There's no shame in doing that.

Comment: @JLRishe...i always try to give complete answers which will work for every jquery becoz you never know which jquery version questioner is using.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.class-lib').addClass('class-func');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/g5fkL1xt/)

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is jQuery addClass.

Put simply:

```
$(".class-lib").addClass('class-func');
```

For more info see: http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: if you're going to answer easy one liners, shoudn't you at least use the right selector?

Answer (score 0):

Here,function will find class "class-lib" and will add class "class-func" to it

```
$('body').find('.class-lib').addClass('class-func');
```